# write y(x) according to sin(d+(ay+b)/cx)=y

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, fourier-series

I end up with the formula $\sin (d+\frac{(ay+b)}{cx})=y $, and try to write $y$ as a function of $x$. There can be multiple solutions (of $y)$ to $\sin(d+\frac{(ay+b)}{cx})=y$ pretending $x$ is known, but I ONLY interested in the least solutions of $y$. The graph of such $y(x)$ is shown below, however, it doesn't help me to write down its math formula.

I guess such $y(x)$ could be a sum of some series of simple functions. Maybe Fourier transformation is helpful, but I have no clue right now. Any suggestions to attack this problem? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I forget to add that a,b,c,d,x are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I am answering your question; so forgive me if I am off topic.

You cannot explicit $y(x)$ but you can do the reverse and get $$x(y)=-\frac{a y+b}{c \left(d-\sin ^{-1}(y)\right)}$$ So, if $y_n=0$, you can obtain the corresponding $x_n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the graph above is constructed by the x(y), however, the range of sin−1(y) is [−π/2 π/2] that is only one part of the desired curve. Now I'am convinced that a closed form of y(x) is impossible, but is it possible to approximated by some series?